# Python Mechanize click button without a form

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I use the Mechanize for filling the form of filtering. 
My code:

```
br = Browser()
br.open(self.domain)
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.find_control("pf_keywords").value = "Lisp"
response = br.click(type='button', nr=0)
#or
response = br.submit(label='Применить фильтр')
```

At the same time, submit button is not in the list of controls for this form.
Html code for this button:

```
<button type="button" class="b-button b-button_flat b-button_flat_green" onclick="$('frm').submit();">Применить фильтр</button>
```

Because of this, using the method click() and submit() impossible to produce form submission. In these methods, there is a search of the desired control with the parameters passed to the control environment forms, as desired button is not there, raise a bug :

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching type 'button', kind 'clickable'
```

What should I do? How can push a button and get the result?

Comment: Not a button ! is Javascript . check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806238/mechanize-python-click-a-button

Comment: OK, following the advice of the question that you have thrown off, I need to emulate that JavaScript does. He does submit this form; how it can be done on the Mechanize?

Comment: Need use selenium ! mechanize don't work on JavaScript buttons.

Comment: I still found the Splinter, maybe it will approach