# python mechanize click on button

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I would like to click on button "query"
     my inspect element gives the following code for the button query and exit.

```
<TD class=font9 colSpan=4 align=center>&nbsp;&nbsp;int pageSize <INPUT class=bg0 size=3 value=10 name=pageSize> Article &nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- <input type="button" class="imagesButton" name="btnPrint" value="打 印" onclick="doPrint(gFormName);">-->&nbsp;&nbsp; <INPUT onclick=doFind(gFormName); class=imagesButton type=button value=query name=Submit> &nbsp;&nbsp; <!--     <input type="button" class="imagesButton4" name="Submit2" value="yesQuery">
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                               --><INPUT onclick=doExit() class=imagesButton type=button value=exit name=Submit5> &nbsp;&nbsp; </TD>
```

I tried the below code for the click

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
submit_response = br.submit(name='Submit',label= 'query')
```

while executing the code I faced an error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'Submit', kind 'clickable', label 'query'
```

can any on help me how to click on button

Comment: may be see http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/32165423/python-mechanize-click-button-without-a-form and  http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1806238/mechanize-python-click-a-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the buttons trigger javascript functions (`"doPrint(gFormName)"`,...)

on http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/764326-using-mechanize-python-navigate-website is a similar problem. it was solved by triggering the javascript action of the button manually

`br.form.action="button_action"`

see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1806238/mechanize-python-click-a-button