# python autofill form in a webpage

Tags: python, forms, html, mechanize

I am trying to fill a form in a webpage that has a single text box and a send button the html looks like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div id="TextContainer" class="textarea-container">
                                    <textarea id="Text" rows="5" maxlength="700" class="form-control remove-border" style="background:none;"></textarea>
                                </div><button id="Send" class="btn btn-primary-outline" type="button" onclick="SendMessage()" style="margin-top:10px" data-loading-text="Loading..."><span class="icon icon-pencil"></span> Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I tried to use mechanize to submit the form with this code

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
response=br.open("https://abcd.com/")
for f in br.forms():
    if f.attrs['class'] == 'form-horizontal':
        br.form = f
text = br.form.find_control(id="Text")
text.value = "something"
br.submit()
```

The code runs without an error, but no submission is happening , how do I do it?

Here is the SendMessage function

```
function SendMessage() {
    var text = $('#Text').val();
    var userId = $('#RecipientId').val();
    if (text.trim() === "")
    {
        $('#TextContainer').css('border-color', 'red');
    }
    else if (new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(text))
    {
        $('#TextContainer').css('border-color', 'red');
        $('#message').html("Links are not allowed in messages");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#Send').button('loading');
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/Messages/SendMessage',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data:
            {
                __RequestVerificationToken: $('<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8MQSRebrM95Pv2f7WNJmKQWGnVR66zie_VVqFsquOCZLDuYRRBPP1yzk_755VDntlD3u0L3P-YYR0-Aqqh1qIjd09HrBg8GNiN_AU48MMlrOtUKDyJyYCJrD918coQPG0dmgkLR3W85gV6P4zObdEMw" />').attr('value'),
                userId: userId,
                text: text
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that the submit button in the HTML form is not of `type=submit` - so mechanise won't know what to do when you call `br.submit()`. The fix is to either change the button type on the HTML website, or tell Browser which button to use for submitting the form:

```
br.submit(type='button', id='Send')
```

The `submit` method takes the same arguments as the HTML Forms API, so I recommend taking a look at the [documentation](http://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms_api.html#mechanize.HTMLForm.click) for more details.

**Update**

The problem here seems to be the JavaScript method attached to the button. Mechanize does not support calling JavaScript functions, hence you won't be able to just use the `.submit()` method to submit the form. Instead, the best option would probably be to read in the `SendMessage()` JavaScript function, which gets called if someone clicks on the Send button, and translate it to Python manually. In the best case it consists of a simple AJAX POST request which is very easy to implement in Python. Please [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806266/3628578) for a related question.

**Second Update**

Given the new information in your question, in particular the JavaScript function, you can now manually implement the POST request inside your Python script. I suggest the use of the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) module which will make the implementation much easier.

```
import requests

data = {
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "CfDJ8MQSRebrM95Pv2f7WNJmKQWGnVR66zie_VVqFsquOCZLDuYRRBPP1yzk_755VDntlD3u0L3P-YYR0-Aqqh1qIjd09HrBg8GNiN_AU48MMlrOtUKDyJyYCJrD918coQPG0dmgkLR3W85gV6P4zObdEMw",
    "userId": "something",
    "text": "something else"
}

response = requests.post("https://example.com/Messages/SendMessage", data=data)
```

`response` will now consist of the response which you can use to check if the request was successfully made. Please note that you might need to read out the `__RequestVerificationToken` with mechanize as I suspect it is generated each time you open the website. You could just read out the HTML source with `html_source = br.read()` and then search for `__RequestVerificationToken` and try to extract the corresponding value.

Comment: Its throwing this error `mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching type 'button', kind 'clickable', id 'Send'`

Comment: Try to just do it by ID, i.e. `br.submit(id='Send')` and see if that works?

Comment: The problem is the `SendMessage()` JavaScript function. I have updated my answer with a suggestion how to fix this.

Comment: I have updated the function, also I know the userId but what about the verification token?

Comment: I updated the response with some suggestions how you could go about it.

Comment: I have already tried that but thats not working response is always showing `<Response [400]>` , maybe after I accessed the url to get the token the token changes and does not work  for the `requests.post`

Comment: I'd guess there are some cookies that might need to be included in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You can give name attribute to your text area like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div id="TextContainer" class="textarea-container">
                                    <textarea id="Text" name="sometext" rows="5" maxlength="700" class="form-control remove-border" style="background:none;"></textarea>
                                </div><button id="Send" class="btn btn-primary-outline" type="button" onclick="SendMessage()" style="margin-top:10px" data-loading-text="Loading..."><span class="icon icon-pencil"></span> Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Then try this out:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://abcd.com/")
br.select_form(nr=0) #in case of just single form you can select form passing nr=0
br["sometext"] = "something"
response  = br.submit()
print(response.read())
```

If it successfully submits form then you can read your response body.